# Cannot parse JSON data returned between [{ and }] Python

Tags: python, json

Here's where I'm starting from:

```
url = 'https://api.example.com/'
bearer_token = 'my_token'

result = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token)}).json()
print(result[3])
```

When I print the `type` of result my JSON results produce, I get a 'list', but I can't parse through it the way one normally would a list. For example, I can't access keys behind [ and {. These areas seem to be treated differently when I try to parse data from them. Some values are accessible by [index]['key'], others are not.

Here's a snippet of my JSON output when I `print(result[3])`:

```
{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 1 10:20:16 +0000 2021', 'id': 1448292507, 'id_str': '1448817927', 'text': 'Lorem ipsum data data data', 'truncated': True, 'entities': {'hashtags': [{'text': 'RedLife', 'indices': [90, 101]}, {'text': 'NS18', 'indices': [102, 107]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_ment': [{'n_name': 'name_1', 'name': 'name_2', 'id': 5232, 'id_str': '32', 'indices': [12, 10]}, {'n_name': 'Lorem', 'name': 'Lorem', 'id': 1372, 'id_str': '72', 'indices': [10, 17]}, {'n_name': 'TV', 'name': 'TV', 'id': 3576, 'id_str': '76', 'indices': [55, 60]}], 'urls': [{'url': 'https://website.com', 'expanded_url': 'https://website'...}
```

When I `print(result[3]['created_at'])`, I get `Wed Oct 1 10:20:16 +0000 2021`. Great!

When I try other keys in the list I get `KeyError`s.

What do I need to do to my JSON data in order to pull all the data I need? And in the case where there exists multiple instances of the same 'key', how do I retrieve the 'value' I'm looking for? Do I just append the index I want like this: `print(result[3]['n_name'][0])`?

Comment: Can you provide which keys you are trying? Often times keys are nested more than you would expect!

Comment: An object wouldn’t have duplicate keys. As stated above, the perceived duplicate must be nested.

Comment: @VincentBuscarello they do seem nested. For the sake of example, let's say I'm looking for the second 'n_name' and the 'expanded_url'

Comment: I think that list is under the entities and user_ment keys.

What does this give you? This should be n_name
`print(result['entities']['user_ment'][0]['n_name'])`

And this should be expanded_url
`print(result['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url'])`

Comment: When it comes to nested data like this, slowly go one layer at a time, printing each item. Usually what is wrong is you are trying to treat a list like a dictionary or vice versa.

Comment: @VincentBuscarello It throws the TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - I can only start with a index by integer. I did figure out the answer I need. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Awesome, great work! if you have the answer you should post it here as an answer too! it will bump your points and help others down the road!

Comment: oh haha result is a list too, that makes sense then.

Comment: Something like `print(result[0]['entities']['user_ment'][0]['n_name'])` should work but I bet you already got that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access `n_name`, you're missing `'entities'` and `'user_ment'` levels in the dict, then you have a list, then again a list

```
result = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {'created_at': 'Wed Oct 1 10:20:16 +0000 2021', 'id': 1448292507,
     'id_str': '1448817927',
     'text': 'Lorem ipsum data data data', 'truncated': True,
     'entities': {
         'hashtags': [{'text': 'RedLife', 'indices': [90, 101]}, {'text': 'NS18', 'indices': [102, 107]}],
         'symbols': [],
         'user_ment': [
             {'n_name': 'name_1', 'name': 'name_2', 'id': 5232, 'id_str': '32', 'indices': [12, 10]},
             {'n_name': 'Lorem', 'name': 'Lorem', 'id': 1372, 'id_str': '72', 'indices': [10, 17]},
             {'n_name': 'TV', 'name': 'TV', 'id': 3576, 'id_str': '76', 'indices': [55, 60]}
         ],
         'urls': [{'url': 'https://website.com', 'expanded_url': 'https://website'}]
     }}
]

x = result[3]['entities']['user_ment'][0]['n_name']
print(x)  # name_1

x = result[3]['entities']['user_ment'][1]['n_name']
print(x)  # Lorem
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is raising the TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I can only start with a index by integer, starting with an index by str throws the error

Comment: @Micadeli of course, the data I show is directly your `result[3]`, see my edit